# Queryset expression using List Comprehension

Tags: python, django

Again I have same problem with query set

Following is the list for exclude some pattern in my query.

```
list = ['AW', 'cons', 'AR', 'AA', 'S1']
```

I am using the list contents one by one from the list and then using in below query set

```
objects_list = XeroLabourIndirect.objects.exclude(
            Q(job_num__istartswith='AW') |
            Q(job_num__istartswith='cons') |
            Q(job_num__istartswith='AR') |
            Q(job_num__istartswith='S1') |
            Q(job_num__istartswith='AA')) if obj else None
```

Instead of using the list content one by one in query set, I want to use my list inside query set with list comprehension method and iterate inside the query and then I have to get the resultant queryset.

For that what I have to do?

I tried something but all ends in syntax error, or some other errors. Please give some solution for my problem

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: `from functools import reduce` and `from operator import or_` and `XeroLabourIndirect.objects.exclude(reduce(or_, (Q(job_num__istartswith=w) for w in list)))`.

Comment: Thanks @martijn pieters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222457/django-building-a-queryset-with-q-objects , this helped me for my solution.

Comment: why not using:
 XeroLabourIndirect.objects.filter(job_num__in = list). I don't test for using  __istartswith_in so can't tell the result

Comment: @NamNguyễn: that's a very different test. That requires `job_num` values to be *equal* to any of those values. The test if they **start** with any of those values.

Comment: Just explored here to see the answer. @MartijnPieters nice answer. :)

Comment: that is why i wondering... can it work __istartswith and __in combo? I have to give it a try late on. Tell me if you got the result. Tks